# Storing variables between shopping and checkout

Tags: cookies, local-storage, netsuite, shopping-cart, checkout

I'm trying to store and use local variables (either in localStorage or cookies) at checkout from the shopping application. I can store them while in shopping but the variables change/null out when in checkout. Is there a way to transfer information between sessions?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom fields on the sales order and set them when "Scriptable Cart and Checkout" is turned on.

Then they transfer between cart and checkout.

I just use a long text and store the value as JSON so the values can be flexible.